# different output for groups and groups USERNAME after adding a username to a group

Tags: command-line, users, group

I stumble across a weird behaviour today.
After adding a user to a new group like so :

```
# gpasswd -a test myuser
```

then connecting to a new bash session, here are the result for `groups` and `groups myuser`:

```
myuser@mycomputer$ groups
wheel myuser
myuser@mycomputer$ groups myuser
wheel myuser test
```

Only if I reboot the output of `groups` will be the same as `groups myuser`, but not necessary showing the groups in the same order.

So my question is simple : why ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because changes to group membership only take effect after starting a new *login* shell. Starting a new non-login interactive shell session (which is what you get when you open a new terminal) is irrelevant.

So, when you run `groups`, that prints the groups your user is currently in. However, those were set up when your user first logged in and cannot be changed until you log in again. Therefore, `groups` doesn't include your new group.

On the other hand, when you run `groups myuser`, the system doesn't look for the groups the *current* user belongs to *at the moment*, it looks up the groups that the user `myuser` belongs to, which it gets by reading the settings file (`/etc/group`, presumably). Since your user is set up to belong to the new group in `/etc/groups`, this command shows that as well, even though you're not *currently* in that group since you haven't logged in again.

Comment: `newgrp` also comes in handy, without logging in again ;-).

Answer (score 3):

- When you run `groups` without an argument, it shows the groups list of the current **process**.  Normally, the list is simply inherited from the parent process, but it is changed by `login`, `newgrp` and similar.
- When you run `groups` with an argument, it shows the groups that are listed (in the user databases) for the specified **user**.  That's the group list that `login` etc. will set the next time it's run for that user.

This is why updating the user/group databases will only affect *future* login sessions - don't expect it to change any processes that are already running.